# Sum of $\sin$ when angles shrink by $1/n$

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis, trigonometric-sums

There are many identities known like

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin (k \cdot \theta + \varphi) = \frac{\sin\left(n \cdot \frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)} \cdot \sin \left(\frac{2 \varphi + (n-1)\cdot \theta}{2} \right)$$

However, in such situations the angles add up and are equidistant. Instead, I pose myself the question whether there is a simplifying formula for
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \cdot \sin \left(\frac{x}{k} \right),$$
particularly,  if $x$ is much larger than $n$.

Comment: The [original version](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/381439/1) is basically asking  for $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin\frac xk$ where $k=n\theta+\varphi$. I just wanted to make sure whether you meant $\sin \left(\frac{n \cdot \theta + \varphi}{k} \right)$ or $\sin \left(\frac{k \cdot \theta + \varphi}{k} \right)$.

Comment: After trying [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D+%5Csin+%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bk%7D+%7D%24&page=1&tm=0&domains=) and [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%7Bn%7D%20%5Csin%20%5Cfrac%7Bx%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1), I found this question: [Estimating $\sum\limits _{n=1}^k \sin \frac x n$ in the form $f(k,x) \sin(g(k,x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1593935).

Comment: @Martin There was indeed an error in the old formula, but I had to add a factor of k to it

Comment: So, the title, which says "angles shrink by $1/n$"?

Answer (score 4):

For large $n$ you may approximate the sum by an integral, which gives
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k \sin (x/k)-nx\simeq \int_0^\infty\bigl(k\sin(x/k)-k\bigr)\,dk=-\tfrac{1}{4}\pi x^2.$$
The plot compares the left-hand-side of this equation for $n=1000$ (blue curve) with the right-hand-side (gold) as a function of $x$.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your input. I like your formula a lot, however, I am interested in situations where $x$ is much larger than $n$ and I am afraid that this is not going to hold anymore then. Or is there a way to improve that formula?

Answer (score 3):

If you rewrite everything using complex exponentials, then it's clear why a sum such as $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sin(k\theta+\phi)$$ has a nice closed formula, since it's just two  geometric sums
$$ e^{i\phi}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} e^{\pm i\theta k}. $$
And if you want $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k\sin(k\theta+\phi)$, it's similar, there are nice formulas for $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}kT^k$. On the other hand, the sum you're asking about looks like
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n k\sin\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)
= \frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \Bigl(ke^{\pi i x/k} + ke^{-\pi i x/k}\Bigr). $$
I don't think that there's a nice closed formula in general for
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n kT^{1/k},\quad\text{nor for}\quad \sum_{k=1}^n T^{1/k}. $$
However, as Carlo indicated, one can often get a good approximation using an integral.